# Range of convergent of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}$ where $a\in\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Range of convergent of  $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}$ where $a\in\Bbb R$

I think that the answer is for $a>1$, but I'm not sure.
this is was my try:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}+\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}$$

1) For $\int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}$ I used comparison test:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan(5)dx}{x^a}\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\pi/2 dx}{x^a}$$

From that I got $a>1$

2) For $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(5x)dx}{x^a}$ I also used comparison test with $\frac{1}{x^{a+2}}$ and got $a>0$.

From both i concluded $a>0$.

Correct me if wrong or if there is a simple way.

Comment: The comparison test is more applicable if you use the bounds:$$\frac{\arctan(5N)}Nx<\arctan(5x)<5x,\quad x\in(0,N)$$

Comment: $1/x^{a+2}$ is not integrable over $(0,1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've identified the two trouble spots, at $0$ and $\infty,$ and written the integral as a sum of integrals to deal with it. Good.  And your answer to 1) is fine.

You have the wrong answer to $2).$ Recall that $\dfrac{\arctan u}{u} \to 1$ as $u\to 0.$ Thus $\arctan (5x)$ is like $5x$ for small $x.$ Thus in 2) you're essentially looking at

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^a}\, dx.$$

Give it another try.

Comment: $a <2$?  I stupidly made the opposite for $[0,1]$  (not my main mistake but one of them.
can you please explain why $\arctan(x)$ is like $x$ for small $x$? i know that the limit of their divide is 1 (when x approach 0), but this is enough?

Comment: Yes, $a<2.$ For the other question: Write the integrand as

$$\frac{\arctan (5x)}{5x}\cdot \frac{5x}{x^a}.$$